# How much Elixir is collected during a match?

Tags: clash-royale

I want to know how much Elixir is produced during a match  (*Not* counting Elixir Collectors and when Elixir bars are full) in order to test a new, costly strategy.
**So, how much Elixir is produced during a match?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Royale Wiki](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Elixir), you get 1 Elixir per 2.8 seconds.
After 2 minutes this goes up to 1 Elixir per 1.4 seconds.
Also, you'll start with 5 Elixir.

This means that during a normal match you get:
5 + (2*60)/2.8 + 60/1.4 = **90** (point something) Elixir.

If the match goes to Sudden Death, this is boosted to total of:
5 + (2*60)/2.8 + 60/1.4 + 60/1.4 = **133** (point something) Elixir, so **43** Elixir more.

Comment: Do not forget, that you start already with 5 Elixir. Although it isn't produced directly it should still be involved in calculations.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 _Very_ good point. I'll add that right away.

Comment: At some point after this answer they've tweaked this a bit. You'll also gain 1 extra elixir at the time the elixir doubling occours. So, you can add 1 to each number.